# Can I use scp to copy files to the home directory without having to specify it?

Tags: scp, home

I've followed [this](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ssh-and-scp-howto-tips-tricks/) tutorial to see how to use `scp` to transfer files to my server. And all is well. So I'm using commands like this:

```
scp examplefile yourusername@yourserver:/home/yourusername/
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way for me to not have to specify the destination with the prepended `/home/yourusername/`. I'm already using the username in the address, is there a way to make the home directory on the remote user the "base" of the file transfer destination?

Or, to clarify, I want to be able to send files to the home directory of the user on the remote computer (`yourusername@yourserver:/home/yourusername/`) with a command like this:

```
scp examplefile yourusername@yourserver
```

Is it possible? Feasible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `username@server:` as the target should be enough, i.e.

```
scp somefile username@server:
```

This would copy the file `somefile` to the server `server` and place it in the home directory of the user `username`.  By "home directory" I mean whatever directory will be the default one that this user arrives in when logging in on the `server` system using `ssh` (most likely `/home/username`, or `/Users/username` on macOS, or `/usr/home/username` on FreeBSD).

Answer (score 3):

or your can do as below instead.

```
scp myfile username@host:./
```

Answer (score -1):

The Maven configuration file uses a different syntax. What your [linked example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45838996/2344631) shows is this

```
<url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com/home/maven</url>
```

So by extension what you want is this

```
<url>scpexe://maven@myserver.com/</url>
```